# Share a Folder with registry key

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, share

I'm googling for a couple of days to find a way to share a folder by command line (in Windows Xp, Vista an 7).
I think I've tried all the code available on internet: I can share a folder but cannot write into it cause I cannot obtain the write/read permission for the "Everyone" user.

I was thinking that maybe there's a way to share a folder by changing a registry key, relating to that folder.

Have you ever heard something like this? Is it possible?? Any other hints?

**SOLVED**: I used first the NET SHARE command (with /GRANT:Evryone, FULL for Windows Vista, 7 and 8, but not in XP, because it doesn't exist in XP such a permission) and THEN the CALCS command like this:

```
NET SHARE shared=C:\shared /GRANT: everyone,FULL

CACLS C:\shared /E /T /C /G "everyone":F
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired using the `net share` command?

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_share.mspx?mfr=true

> **Examples**
>
> To display information about shared resources on the computer, type:
>
> net share
>
> To share a computer's C:\Data directory with the share name DataShare
>   and include a remark, type:
>
> `net share DataShare=c:\Data /remark:"For department 123."`
>
> To stop sharing the DataShare folder you created in the previous
>   example, type:
>
> `net share DataShare /delete`
>
> To share a computer's C:\Art Lst directory with the share name List,
>   type:
>
> `net share list="c:\art lst"`

**Granting Access**

This post talks about different version of Windows servers defaulting to either read-only access or everyone full access, so you can use the `/grant` switch if running on Windows 2003

http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/3190-command-line-tool-share-permissions.html

> `NET SHARE share$=<filepath>  /GRANT:user,permission`

Comment: I've tried the both the net share and cacls commands but the folder is not really completely shared: I can access it, but I cannot write folder or files into it. I observed that the write/read permission for the Everyone folder is not set. It seems such an easy thing to do with the net share command, but it doesn't work as I wish..

Comment: What version of Windows are you testing this on? I don't think the `grant` switch is supported by XP. Also what are the permissions on the "share" when you right click the shared folder and select "sharing and security...". Put you answer to my questions in your original question rather than reply to this comment so others can see it

Comment: Also, does the user account that you're running your code with have rights to create a shared folder with Everyone, full control? If not, try running it as an "Administrator"

Answer (score 1):

You can share a folder with cmd using this

```
net share MyShare=C:\FolderToShare
```

To set permissions you can use this

```
cacls C:\FolderToShare /g Everyone:F
```

Alternatively type this to skip the confirmation

```
echo y| cacls C:\FolderToShare /g Everyone:F
```

which will give `Everyone` full control to the folder. Type `cacls /?` in cmd for a list of permission options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio installed you can try writing a small VB application to accomplish this task. If your main application is not a VB application you could "shell" out to the helper app to create the share on your behalf.

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/network/netshareadd.htm